# How to Download Images and video from server before application start

Tags: android, android-emulator

My application size is more than 120 MB. it's content lots of images and Videos.
so that i want to download all images and videos 1st in SD cards and after that my application start.
This procedure work when i install application in device.
after downloading all images and videos My application start.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a service to download the content from the server.
2. Add your activity to it for custom event listening
3. Broadcast event [Completion, Part-Completion] to the registered listener when the service is able to do the job.
4. Till that time either show a splash screen or a download screen with progress bar indicating download progress.
5. On listening to "Completion" notification you can show the main activity.

Hope this helps

Comment: If Connection is lost, you can always restart from the last file. If you track the progress file wise.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `Splash` `Activity` for your application. So this will be an `Activity` that displays only a picture, let say your application logo or something similar. Then check if your app has all ready downloaded the videos and photos, you can do this by keeping a boolean field in `SharedPreferences` let say `DATA_DOWNLOADED`. If the data is not downloaded then you will need to start s `Service` that will download all the data, also display a `ProgressIndicator` and a message for the user, that data is being downloaded.

Once the data is downloaded you mark the `DATA_DOWNLOADED` field in your `SharedPreferences` and you start the next `Activity`.

Good luck.

Comment: ok... then you should reconsider editing a little your question and be more precise.